# minuscule text in a standalone environment

Tags: fonts, fontsize, scaling, text, tikzscale

The `{memoir}` document class allows for text smaller than `\tiny`, with the `\miniscule` command, which can be useful, but I never find myself needing to write an actual memoir. I tend to use either `{article}` or `{\standalone}`, or a combination of the two. For instance I might start an article and as the main file, draw standalone diagrams in separate files, and insert the graphics with something like:

```
    \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{illustration.pdf}}
```

After all, the best thing about vectors is they're scalable.
Here's a quick demo of a situation where `\miniscule` text might be useful:

[image]

It looks okay, but I want to make the ***[32-bit]*** text smaller:

(`\textcolor{red!50!black!50}{\tiny{[32-bit]}}`)

```
%%% Document Preamble %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
%%% Tikz Preamble %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  % Set Default Arrowheads, Node Distance, etc.
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [-{>[scale=3,length=width=2]}, >=Stealth, 
    node distance=15mm, auto]
%%% Define Object Types %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \tikzstyle{red_ball} = [draw, circle, fill=red!20, 
    text width=1.5em, minimum height=2.5em, text centered]
  \tikzstyle{blue_ball} = [draw, circle, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=1.5em, minimum height=2.5em, text centered]
%%% Place Nodes %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Associate Objects with Text
    \node[red_ball](Pbi) {$P_{\beta_{i}}$};
    \node[blue_ball, below of=Pbi](XOR) {$\oplus$};
    % Additional Annotations
    \node[yshift=12mm, below of=Pbi](PbiBits) 
      {\textcolor{red!50!black!50}{\tiny{[32-bit]}}};
%%% Draw Lines, Arrows, etc. %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \draw[->](Pbi)--(XOR);
%%% Close Tikz Environment %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \end{tikzpicture}
%%% Close Main Environment %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: note `\tiny{[32-bit]}` should be `\tiny [32-bit]` font sizes do not take an argument you could use `\fontsize{3pt}{4pt}\selectfont` with `fix-cm` package if you use the standard cm fonts

Comment: @David Seems to work with or without braces, but duly noted. Actually, I tried that with the `fix-cm` package but it seemed to go ignored. I think Computer Modern fonts are the default; I haven't changed them. I'll try again, thanks.

Comment: yes the braces do nothing so it works with or without them but looksmisleading as you might expect `\tiny{one} two three` to just make `one` tiny but it applies to two and three as well. without fix-cm your will get font substitutions to a fixed set of sizes for cm, and will not be able to go below 5pt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a very tiny font, but you need a freely scalable font. For the standard fonts, `fix-cm` is needed.

```latex
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\veryverytiny}{\fontsize{3}{3}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
%%% Tikz Preamble %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Set Default Arrowheads, Node Distance, etc.
\begin{tikzpicture}[-{>[scale=3,length=width=2]},>=Stealth,node distance=15mm,auto]
%%% Define Object Types %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{
  red_ball/.style = {
    draw, circle, fill=red!20, text width=1.5em, minimum height=2.5em, text centered
  },
  blue_ball/.style = {
    draw, circle, fill=blue!20, text width=1.5em, minimum height=2.5em, text centered
  },
}
%%% Place Nodes %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Associate Objects with Text
\node[red_ball](Pbi) {$P_{\beta_{i}}$};
\node[blue_ball, below of=Pbi](XOR) {$\oplus$};
% Additional Annotations
\node[yshift=12mm, below of=Pbi](PbiBits) {\textcolor{red!50!black!50}{\veryverytiny[32-bit]}};
%%% Draw Lines, Arrows, etc. %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw[->](Pbi)--(XOR);
%%% Close Tikz Environment %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{tikzpicture}
%%% Close Main Environment %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\tikzstyle` has been deprecated for some years.

I removed the `varwidth` option, because not needed.

Comment: _"Note that `\tikzstyle` has been deprecated for some years."_ Is that right? How come? I use it a lot. I mostly learn syntax by example and studying old code, so I guess it's bound too happen. Sometimes vestigial bits and pieces creep in like the `varwidth` you mentioned. Anyway I'll try this method; much appreciated.

Comment: @tjt263 Read the quote from Till Tantau in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52379/4427

Comment: Quick question: Why do you use `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` instead of `\usepackage{fix-cm}`?

Comment: @tjt263 Some fonts are loaded as soon as `\documentclass` is executed and would not obey properly to scaling, so doing `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` prevents this possible issue. If you have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` you can load `fix-cm` also after `\documentclass`.